# setTimeout(fun) with a single argument? (Timeout not specified)

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The `HTML5` [specifications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) states that `setTimeout` can be run without the additional "timeout" argument which is supposed to say after how many milliseconds will the function "handler" be scheduled.

```
handle = window . setTimeout( handler [, timeout [, arguments ] ] )
   Schedules a timeout to run handler after timeout milliseconds. Any arguments are passed straight through to the handler.
```

However, I failed to find anywhere which explains what happens when no "timeout" time period is set.

An example usage is, the [animation implementation](http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L2932) int the Raphael library.

```
animationElements[length] && win.setTimeout(animation);
```

Comment: All current major browsers are able to accept a single argument, so to avoid any confusion it's worth pointing out that a browser does not have to be HTML5 compliant to support this.

Comment: This is a splendid way of doing deferred procedure calls in JS - "do X later/not-right-now". If you're inside an event handler, it may be a bad time to call some function because of state/re-entrancy issues. Note that you cannot guarantee the actual execution time, but it's "soon".

Comment: @Andy Mozilla MDC states the millisecond as a mandatory parameter.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson: Indeed, and it's also a great way to delay execution with the possibility of cancelling it if a particular event fires.  I've used this technique numerous times and it's really useful.

Comment: Related: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](/q/779379/4642212), [NodeJS - setTimeout(fn,0) vs setImmediate(fn)](/q/24117267/4642212).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#get-the-timeout

> 1. Let timeout be the second argument to
>      the method, or zero if the argument
>      was omitted.

Comment: Beat me to it :-) +1.  I was going to add to my own answer (but may as well add it here) that just because the timeout argument is 0 doesn't necessarily mean it will run instantly, it will still be queued to run when the thread becomes idle, e.g. after all current code execution is finished.

Comment: FYI, the above referenced document has been changed  so that it now just reads: "Let timeout be the second argument to the method." However, the Mozilla documentation does document this behavior here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout